# Increase the caching file size on chrome (similiar to browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size on firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, caching, chromium, browser-cache

We run a system which shows some medias (images, videos, etc.).
As system we have a ubuntu with a kiosk google chrome, now we have the issue that larger files are not cached.

As example we have a video which is 54mb large and will be redownloaded every time.
The header (max-age, etag) etc. are correct on the backend, as smaller files are cached correctly.

For Firefox we found the option "browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size", after we increased that option 100mb, the video with 54mb was cached on firefox.

Is there a similar option for google chrome ?

Thanks you in advance.

I tried searching for a parameter to increase the limit, but don't found one.
I found the option "media-cache-size" which was removed a lot years ago.
There is the option "--disk-cache-size" which defines the size of the whole cache (instead per file).
I don't event found out what the limit for the cache is.